# Set up PostgreSQL: initdb error

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to set up PostgreSQL on my server. I installed it as well as several packages using the apt-get command.

Then I connected to the postgres user using: `sudo su - postgres`. It worked fine.

Then I wanted to create a Database cluster. I ran:

```
initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

and got:

```
initdb: Postgres-XC node name is mandatory
Try "initdb --help" for more information.
```

Comment: [Postgres-XC](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Postgres-XC) isn't bare bones postgres. As noted, [`initdb`](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/docs/1_1/creating-cluster.html) needs a node name for PG-XC.

Comment: You apparently installed Postgres-XC, not PostgreSQL

Comment: ah.... that would explain why tutorials are not herpfull Thanks

Comment: Well I removed Postgres-xc and now I have this error: postgres@ChemAlive:~$ initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
The program 'initdb' is currently not installed. To run 'initdb' please ask your administrator to install the package 'postgres-xc'

Comment: @Laetis What OS/Distribution is this on?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu for server. Regarding postgres I have curently that installed: postgresql, postgresql-9.3,postgresql-client-9.3, postgresql-client-common, postgresql-common

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/371737/install-postgresql-why-is-initdb-unavailable)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks I now understood Postgres-XC and PostgreSQL  are two different things. But why is it still asking for Postgres-XC?

Comment: @dhke I am lauching the commend under postgres account

Comment: @Laetis Because debian (actually debian-alternatives) looks up the packages which provide the respective command and gives a suggestion based on that. But debian does the database setup using its own tools and therefore *hides* initdb (at `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/initdb`). You are supposed to use `pg_createcluster` and friends to manage your databases. See `/usr/share/doc/postgresql-9.3/README.Debian.gz` for details.

Comment: Indeed you were write, I used  /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data instead and it's fine now. thanks